# Java print 2D array element connections

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array as below:

```
String[][] x = {{"A1", "A2"}, {"B1", "B2"}, {"C1", "C2"}};
```

I want to print out the element connections like this:

```
A1-B1-C1
A1-B1-C2
A1-B2-C1
A1-B2-C2
A2-B1-C1
A2-B1-C2
A2-B2-C1
A2-B2-C2
```

Is there any suggestion?
Thanks.

Comment: Made any attempt?

Answer (score 0):

```
package staticTryOuts;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] x = {{"A1", "A2"}, {"B1", "B2"}, {"C1", "C2"}};
        for(int i=0;i<x[0].length;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<x[1].length;j++) {
                for(int k=0;k<x[2].length;k++) {
                    System.out.println(x[0][i]+"-"+x[1][j]+"-"+x[2][k]);

                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```